# ¿Hay diferencia entre if y elif?

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre anidar muchos `if` o anidar un `if` seguido de `elif`? Por ejemplo:

Qué diferencia hay entre ésto:

```
if (condición):

if (condicion):

else:
```

y ésto:

```
if (condición):

elif (condicion):

else:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay una diferencia fundamental, si usas `if` encadenados **todas las expresiones son evaluadas siempre**, aunque una previa sea cierta:

```
a = 15
if a % 5 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 5")
if a % 3 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 3")
```

> ```
> 15 es divisible entre 5
> 15 es divisible entre 3
> ```

Si usas `elif`, en el **momento que una condición anterior (el `if` u otro `elif`) se cumpla, ese `elif` y el resto que le sigan no se evalúan siquiera**:

```
a = 15

if a % 5 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 5")
elif a % 3 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 3")
```

> ```
> 15 es divisible entre 5
> ```

```
a = 6
if a % 5 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 5")
elif a % 3 == 0:
    print(f"{a} es divisible entre 3")
```

> ```
> 6 es divisible entre 3
> ```

Puedes traducir el bloque:

```
if x:
    pass
elif y:
    pass
elif z:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

por algo como:

```
si `x` es cierta:
    hacer algo
si `x` no es cierta pero `y` si lo es:
    hacer otra cosa
si `x` no es cierta ni tampoco `y` pero `z` si lo es:
    hacer otra cosa
si nada de lo anterior es cierto:
    hacer otra cosa
```

Solo que el intérprete usa un cortocircuito, en el momento que una condición se cumpla pasa olímpicamente de evaluar el resto del bloque y pasa a ejecutar el código siguiente al estamento `if-elif-else`.

En los casos en los que las condiciones sean excluyentes (si una se cumple, las otras son falsas) debes usar siempre `elif` porque **es más eficiente**:

```
n = 1

if n == 0:
    print("¡Soy un 0!")
elif n == 1:
    print("¡Soy un 1!")
else:
    print("¡No se lo que soy!, solo se contar hasta 1...!")
```

si usas un `if` y no un `elif` la expresión  `n == 1` se evalúa  aunque el número sea un 0, no tiene sentido alguno, ya sabemos que no puede ser un 1 en este punto. Usar un `if` encadenado en este caso solo sirve para malgastar ciclos de CPU evaluando una expresión que sabemos que siempre va a ser falsa si la primera no lo es.

Para el resto de casos dependerá de la lógica que quieras seguir. En el primer ejemplo de la respuesta:

- Si quieres que se compruebe si el número es divisible entre 5 y además entre 3 (sin importar si es o no divisible entre 5) pues debes usar `if` encadenados.
- Si quieres que se haga algo si es divisible entre 5 y se detenga ahí, pero que **si no lo es** se compruebe a continuación si es divisible entre 3 y haga otra cosa, entonces debes usar `if-elif`.