# Convertir código Java a Python, problema al usar isinstance en lugar de instanceof

Tags: java, python

¿Cómo puedo convertir éstas lineas de código Java a Python? He intentado lo siguiente, pero no me funcionó correctamente

Mi intento en Python

```
for i in electroList:
    if(electroList[i] isinstance(object, Electrodomestico) == True):
        electros += electroList[i].precioFinal()
    if(electroList[i] isinstance(object, Lavadora) == True):
        lavadoras += electroList[i].precioFinal()
    if(electroList[i] isinstance(object, Television) == True):
        tvs += electroList[i].precioFinal()
```

en Java:

```
for(int i=0;i<listaElectrodomesticos.length;i++){

    if(listaElectrodomesticos[i] instanceof Electrodomestico){
        sumaElectrodomesticos+=listaElectrodomesticos[i].precioFinal();
    }
    if(listaElectrodomesticos[i] instanceof Lavadora){
        sumaLavadoras+=listaElectrodomesticos[i].precioFinal();
    }
    if(listaElectrodomesticos[i] instanceof Television){
        sumaTelevisiones+=listaElectrodomesticos[i].precioFinal();
    }
}
```

He leído en otras páginas, pero no comprendo bien cómo funcionan las instancias en Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## El ciclo for in

El `for` en Python **siempre itera sobre un iterador**.  Para un rango de enteros se debe usar `range()` y el `for in` iterará sobre el iterable que genera:

```
for i in range(len(listaElectrodomesticos)):
    listaElectrodomesticos[i]...
```

Ejemplo:

```
lista = ["Hola", "StackOverflowers"]
for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[i])
```

> ```
> Hola
> StackOverflowers
> ```

Pero es mucho más eficiente iterar directamente sobre la lista, con el `for`, pero en tal caso a la variable asociada al ciclo se asocia una referencia a cada item directamente:

```
for item in listaElectrodomesticos:
    item...
```

Ejemplo:

```
lista = ["Hola", "StackOverflowers"]
for palabra in lista:
    print(palabra)
```

> ```
> Hola
> StackOverflowers
> ```

---

## `isinstance()`

Primero, el condicional:

```
if (electroList[i] isinstance(object, Electrodomestico) == True):
```

es directamente sintaxis inválida, por hacer ésto`if (objeto objeto)`.

En cuanto a como comprobar si un objeto es instancia de otro:

- `isinstance` en el caso de Python es una [**función** builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).
- El primer argumento es una referencia al objeto del que quieres comprobar si es instancia de algo.
- El segundo argumento es una referencia al objeto del que quieres ver si el primero es instancia de él (una clase/tipo). También puede ser un iterable de clases/tipos, en cuyo caso se comprobará si el primer argumento es instancia de alguno de ellos (`or`).

Si haces:

```
isinstance(object, Electrodomestico)
```

siempre será False. [`object` es la clase base de la que deriva cualquier objeto en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343143/funcionamiento-del-operador-is/343149#343149), todos, sin excepción. La única clase que no deriva de nada es el propio `object`. Por lo tanto, dado que compruebas **si `object` es instancia de `Electrodomestico`**, ésto siempre va a ser `False`. `Electrodomestico` si  es siempre instancia de `object`, pero como cualquier otro objeto que exista.

Debe ser:

```
isistance(item, Electrodomestico)
```

dónde item es el objeto de la lista.

Además, hacer `if isistance(item, Electrodomestico) == True:` aunque sintácticamente correcto y funcional, no es convencionalmente correcto. [`True` es un singleton, por lo que se debe usar el operador de identidad `is`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343143/funcionamiento-del-operador-is/343149#343149) no el operador de igualdad si se quiere comprobar si algo **es el objeto `True`**. Ahora bien, si solo queremos saber si algo se evalúa como verdadero, como éste caso, no se debe usar siquiera operador, simplemente:

```
if isinstance(item, Electrodomestico):
```

Ejemplos:

```
n = 3.14

if isistance(n, int):
    print("Es un entero")
else:
    print("No es un entero")
```

> No es un entero

```
n = 3.14

if isistance(n, float):
    print("Es un float")
else:
    print("No es un foat")
```

> Es un float

```
n = 3.14

if isistance(n, (int, float)):
    print("Es un entero o un float")
else:
    print("No es un entero ni un float")
```

> Es un entero o un float

---

## Código final

```
for item in electroList:
    if isinstance(item, Electrodomestico):
        electros += item.precioFinal()
    if isinstance(item, Lavadora):
        lavadoras += item.precioFinal()
    elif isinstance(item, Television):
        tvs += item.precioFinal()
```

Debes por eficiencia usar siempre `if - elif` si estás ante condiciones mutuamente excluyentes:

- [¿Hay diferencia entre if y elif?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/345599/15089)

En principio si un objeto es una lavadora no sería una televisión, no deberíamos siquiera comprobarlo (a no ser que existan las "televidoras"...XD). He dejado los dos primero con `if` porque no se si quieres que sean excluyentes, es decir, si un objeto es un electrodomestico si puede ser también una lavadora o una televisión, pero si de ejecutarse el primer `if` los otros dos no se cumplirían, entonces lo apropiado es:

```
for item in electroList:
    if isinstance(item, Electrodomestico):
        electros += item.precioFinal()
    elif isinstance(item, Lavadora):
        lavadoras += item.precioFinal()
    elif isinstance(item, Television):
        tvs += item.precioFinal()
```

---

Como nota aparte, [las convenciones de estilo para código Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) marcan que los nombres de variables deben ser siempre en minúsculas usando `_` como separador de palabras. Es solo una convención, pero el nombre de tu lista de items debería ser `electro_list` y no `electroList`. Las mayúsculas con `CamelCase` se reservan para nombres de clases exclusivamente y `TODO_MAYÚSCULAS` para denotar constantes, el resto (nombres de métodos, funciones, variables y módulos), deben usar `todo_en _minúsculas`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me ha servido bastante