# ¿Cómo puedo salir de un bucle while cuando una variable cambie de valor?

Tags: python, bucles, while

estoy intentando desarrollar un programa el cual realice una serie de operaciones matemáticas dependiendo del valor que introduzcas por consola a una variable.

Esa parte ya está programada y funcionando, el problema es que quiero que cuando esa variable no coincida con los número asignados para la realización de cada tarea informe al usuario de su error y le de la oportunidad de introducir de nuevo la fórmula.

Ahí es donde empiezan los bugs porque también quiero limitarlo a 2 intentos (para que el usuario no pueda entrar en un bucle infinito) no soy capaz de hacerlo, porque constantemente está ejecutando el bucle aunque la fórmula que se haya introducido sea la correcta. Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
import math

print("Programa que calcule los ejercicios de las páginas 34, 36 y 38")
print("-------------------------------------------")

print("Estos son los números que tendrás que introducir para seleccionar la fórmula: ")
print("Calcular el strock de seguridad = 1, Calcular el Stock máximo = 2, Calcular el volumen óptimo del pedido = 3")


seleccionar_formula = int(input("Por favor seleccione la formúla deseada: "))

intentos = 0

while seleccionar_formula != 1 or 2 or 3:
    print("Has seleccionado una fórmula incorrecta")
    intentos = intentos + 1
    seleccionar_formula = int(input("Por favor seleccione la formúla deseada: "))
    if intentos == 2:
        break

if seleccionar_formula == 1:
    VM = int(input("Por favor, introduzca las ventas medias: "))
    PE = int(input("Por favor, introduzca el plazo medio de entrega: "))
    PME = int(input("Por favor, introduza el plazo máximo de entrega: "))
    SS = (PME - PE) * VM
    print("El Stock de seguridad es de: " + str(SS) + str(" unidades"))
if seleccionar_formula == 2:
    stock_seguridad = int(input("Por favor, introduzca el Stock de seguridad: "))
    unidades_sumar = int(input("Por favor, introduzca el número total de unidades a sumar: "))
    SM = stock_seguridad + unidades_sumar
    print("El stock máximo es de: " + str(SM) + str(" Unidades"))
if seleccionar_formula == 3:
    K = int(input("Por favor, introduzca el coste de cada pedido: "))
    D = int(input("Por favor, introduzca la demanda anual: "))
    G = int(input("Por favor, introduzca el coste anual por cada unidad almacenada: "))
    primer_calculo = 2*K*D/G
    Q = math.sqrt(primer_calculo)
    print("El volumen óptimo de pedido es: " + str( Q ) + str("unidades"))
```

Gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos errores, ambos en el propio `while` y su condición:

- El primero es de lógica, quieres comprobar si el número es 1, 2 o 3. Pero usas una desigualdad, por lo que no debes usar `or` sino `and`. Ahora mismo intentas hacer algo como:

  > mientras seleccionar_formula sea diferente de 1 de 2 o de 3:

  imagina que `seleccionar_formula` es 3, lo primero que se evalúa es ¿es `seleccionar_formula` diferente de 1?. Cómo lo es y estamos en un `or`, automáticamente ni se evalúan el resto del condicional, el `or` es `True`. Debe ser por tanto:

  > mientras seleccionar_formula sea diferente de 1 y de 2 y de 3:
- El segundo es muy común en Python, ésto:

  ```
  seleccionar_formula != 1 or 2 or 3:
  ```

  es en realidad:

  ```
  seleccionar_formula != 1 or True or True
  ```

  cualquier entero diferente de 0 es evaluado como `True`.

  Debe ser:

  ```
  while seleccionar_formula != 1 and seleccionar_formula != 2 and seleccionar_formula =! 3:
  ```

  o usando un contenedor y el operador de pertenencia:

  ```
  while seleccionar_formula not in (1, 2, 3):
  ```

  o incluso:

  ```
  while seleccionar_formula not in range(1, 4):
  ```

Dos observaciones:

- **No conviertas la entrada a entero**, no sirve para nada, es más ineficiente y lo único que puedes conseguir es que el usuario ingrese algo que no sea un entero y tengas una excepción. Compara con cadenas directamente.
- **No uses `if` encadenados si son mutuamente excluyentes**, es ineficiente, usa `if-elif`:

  - [¿Hay diferencia entre if y elif?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/345599/15089)

En Python  >= 3.8 hay una forma mucho más simple de emular un `do-while`, usando expresiones de asignación:

**`Python  >= 3.8`**

```
import math


print("Programa que calcule los ejercicios de las páginas 34, 36 y 38")
print("-------------------------------------------")

print(("Estos son los números que tendrás que introducir"
       "para seleccionar la fórmula: "
       ))
print(("  1. Calcular el strock de seguridad.\n"
       "  2. Calcular el Stock máximo.\n"
       "  3. Calcular el volumen óptimo del pedido."
       )) 

intentos = 2
cad = "Por favor seleccione la formúla deseada: "
while (sel:= input(cad)) not in ("1", "2", "3") and (intentos:= intentos - 1):
    print("Has seleccionado una fórmula incorrecta")

if sel == "1":
    pass
elif sel == "2":
    pass
elif sel == "3":
    pass
```

Comment: Ohhhh... es verdad, no tenia ningún tipo de sentido. Muchas gracias de verdad <3, gracias también por las observaciones, me parecía un poco chapucero el código.

Comment: @Christian_Corti05 Si consideras que esta respuesta es la correcta y la que te ha servido, marcala con el "tick verde" de la izquierda para marcar la pregunta como contestada y así ayudar a futuras personas que tengan este mismo problema.